# Uncaught ReferenceError: add_row_weekly is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

what wrong in this code? I get undefined function error for javascript.

1-

> Uncaught ReferenceError: add_row_weekly is not defined

2-

> Uncaught ReferenceError: add_link_menu is not defined

3- and some other like that.

I searched in many websites but can't solve. I am not a developer

Thanks

```
<div class="fields fields3">
<label class="title">کلاس آیکن:</label>
<input dir="ltr" type="text" id="menu_link_icon[]" name="menu_link_icon[]" value="
<?php echo $menu['menu_link_icon'][$i];
 
?>" placeholder="
<?php bloginfo('url');
 
?>">
</div>
<span class="close" onclick="$(this).parent().slideUp(function(){$(this).remove();
});
"><i class="icon-remove"></i></span>
</div>

<?php } 
?>
</div>
<button type="button" class="add_link_menu" onclick="add_link_menu();
">افزودن لینک</button>
<script>
function add_link_menu(){ var rand_num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000000) + 1000);
 $("#add_link").append('<div class="item"><div class="fields fields3"><div class="title">عنوان لینک :</div><input type="text" name="menu_link_name[]" placeholder="باکس آفیس"></div><div class="fields fields3"><label class="title">آدرس لینک :</label><input dir="ltr" type="text" id="menu_link_url[]" name="menu_link_url[]" placeholder="
<?php bloginfo('url');
 
?>"></div><div class="fields fields3"><label class="title">عنوان انگلیسی :</label><input dir="ltr" type="text" id="menu_link_name_en[]" name="menu_link_name_en[]" placeholder="مثال : Menu Link Name"></div><div class="fields fields3"><label class="title">کلاس آیکن :</label><input dir="ltr" type="text" id="menu_link_icon[]" name="menu_link_icon[]" placeholder="مثال : icon-Movie"></div><span class="close" onclick="$(this).parent().slideUp(function(){$(this).remove();
});
"><i class="icon-remove"></i></span></div>');
 $('div[id=hide]').slideDown(function(){ $(this).removeAttr('id');
 $(this).removeAttr('style');
 });
 }
</script>
</div><!-- content -->
</div><!-- i_sections web_section -->
<div class="i_sections jadvalpakhsh_section" id="jadvalpakhsh" style="display:none">
<div class="content">
<div class="fields">
<label class="title" for="active_weekly_table">نمایش و فعال سازی جدول پخش هفتگی :</label>
<label class="switch">
<input type="checkbox" value="on" id="active_weekly_table" name="active_weekly_table" 
<?php echo ds_option('active_weekly_table') == 'on' ? "checked":"";
 
?> onclick="validate()">
<div class="slider round"></div>
</label>
</div>
<div id="add_row">

<?php $week = ds_option('weekly_table');
 for($i = 0;
$i < count($week['week_day']);
$i++){ 
?>
<div class="items">
<div class="fields fields4">
<div class="title">در روز :</div>
<select id="week_day[]" name="week_day[]">
<option value="0" 
<?php if ( $week['week_day'][$i] == '0' ) echo 'selected="selected"';
 
?>>شنبه</option>
<option value="1" 
<?php if ( $week['week_day'][$i] == '1' ) echo 'selected="selected"';
 
?>>یکشنبه</option>
<option value="2" 
<?php if ( $week['week_day'][$i] == '2' ) echo 'selected="selected"';
 
?>>دوشنبه</option>
<option value="3" 
<?php if ( $week['week_day'][$i] == '3' ) echo 'selected="selected"';
 
?>>سشنبه</option>
<option value="4" 
<?php if ( $week['week_day'][$i] == '4' ) echo 'selected="selected"';
 
?>>چهارشنبه</option>
<option value="5" 
<?php if ( $week['week_day'][$i] == '5' ) echo 'selected="selected"';
 
?>>پنجشنبه</option>
<option value="6" 
<?php if ( $week['week_day'][$i] == '6' ) echo 'selected="selected"';
 
?>>جمعه</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="fields fields4">
<div class="title">عنوان سریال :</div>
<input type="text" name="name_series[]" value="
<?php echo $week['name_series'][$i];
 
?>" placeholder="نام سریال">
</div>
<?php } 
?>
</div>
<button type="button" class="add_row_weekly" onclick="add_row_weekly();
">افزودن زمان پخش سریال جدید</button>
<script>
function add_row_weekly(){ var rand_num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000000) + 1000);
 $("#add_row").append('<div class="items"><div class="fields fields4"> <div class="title">در روز :</div><select id="week_day[]" name="week_day[]"><option value="0" 
<?php if ( $week['week_day'][$i] == '0' ) echo 'selected="selected"';
 
?>>شنبه</option><option value="1" 
<?php if ( $week['week_day'][$i] == '1' ) echo 'selected="selected"';
 
?>>یکشنبه</option><option value="2" 
<?php if ( $week['week_day'][$i] == '2' ) echo 'selected="selected"';
 
?>>دوشنبه</option><option value="3" 
<?php if ( $week['week_day'][$i] == '3' ) echo 'selected="selected"';
 
?>>سشنبه</option><option value="4" 
<?php if ( $week['week_day'][$i] == '4' ) echo 'selected="selected"';
 
?>>چهارشنبه</option><option value="5" 
<?php if ( $week['week_day'][$i] == '5' ) echo 'selected="selected"';
 
?>>پنجشنبه</option><option value="6" 
<?php if ( $week['week_day'][$i] == '6' ) echo 'selected="selected"';
 
?>>جمعه</option></select></div><div class="fields fields4"><div class="title">عنوان سریال :</div><input type="text" name="name_series[]" placeholder="نام سریال"></div><div class="fields fields4"><label class="title">آدرس سریال :</label><input dir="ltr" type="text" id="url_series[]" name="url_series[]" placeholder="
<?php bloginfo('url');
 
?>"></div><div class="fields fields4"><label class="title">شبکه پخش کننده :</label><input dir="ltr" type="text" id="network_series[]" name="network_series[]" placeholder="مثال : HBO"></div><div class="fields fields4"><label class="title">قسمت :</label><input dir="ltr" type="text" id="part_series[]" name="part_series[]" placeholder="مثال : اول"></div><div class="fields fields4"><label class="title">فصل :</label><input dir="ltr" type="text" id="season_series[]" name="season_series[]" placeholder="مثال : دوم"></div><div class="fields fields4"><div class="des">لینک یک تصویر ۲۵۰px × ۴۵px قرار دهید</div><label class="title">لینک کاور :</label><input dir="ltr" type="text" id="cover_series[]" name="cover_series[]" placeholder="
<?php bloginfo('url');
 
?>/cover_series.png"></div><span class="close" onclick="$(this).parent().slideUp(function(){$(this).remove();
});
"><i class="icon-remove"></i></span></div>');
 $('div[id=hide]').slideDown(function(){ $(this).removeAttr('id');
 $(this).removeAttr('style');
 });
 }
</script>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @CBroe Thanks but i not understand. can you work on my code?

Comment: sorry i not understand.

Comment: i add function foo(); before this line <button type="button" class="add_link_menu" onclick="add_link_menu();
">افزودن لینک</button>

Comment: @CBroe "When you use “old-school” event handling via HTML attributes, then the function must exist before the element." That's not true. See: https://jsfiddle.net/3qhtdw9r/

Comment: please see this and change: https://jsfiddle.net/masoudnkh/qzwm547u/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors tell you that the functions your code tries to use do not exist at the point when they are attempted to be invoked. Let me show you an illustrative example of what your problem is:

## Incorrect

```
foo();
function foo() {}
```

The reason this is incorrect is that it tries to call `foo` ***before*** it has been created.

## Correct

```
function foo() {}
foo();
```

This is correct because `foo` has been called when it already exists.

## Your functions

Are called before they are defined. I advise you to move your script tags into the head tag to fix this. If you need more help, then you need to point out the exact lines where the issue happens and show your generated markup taken from browser page source, because we do not have your project and your PHP code will not work for us, unless you provide extra information about your project's PHP side. The error tells you where it happens in the console, you need to find the exact location of the error and point it out to us.

EDIT

Fixed code:

```
<div id="add_link_menu">
</div>
<div class="content">
    <button type="button" class="add_link_menu" onclick="add_link_menu();">Add link button</button>
    <script>
        function add_link_menu() { 
            var rand_num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000000) + 1000);
            $("#add_link_menu").append(`
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="fields fields3">
                        <div class="title">عنوان لینک :</div>
                        <input type="text" name="menu_link_name[]" placeholder="باکس آفیس"></div>
                        <div class="fields fields3">
                            <label class="title">آدرس لینک :</label>
                            <input dir="ltr" type="text" id="menu_link_url[]" name="menu_link_url[]" placeholder="someurl">
                        </div>
                        <div class="fields fields3">
                            <label class="title">عنوان انگلیسی :</label>
                            <input dir="ltr" type="text" id="menu_link_name_en[]" name="menu_link_name_en[]" placeholder="مثال : Menu Link Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="fields fields3">
                            <label class="title">کلاس آیکن :</label>
                            <input dir="ltr" type="text" id="menu_link_icon[]" name="menu_link_icon[]" placeholder="مثال : icon-Movie">
                        </div>
                        <span class="close" onclick="$(this).parent().slideUp(function(){$(this).remove();});">
                            <i class="icon-remove"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>`);
            $('div[id=hide]').slideDown(function(){ 
                $(this).removeAttr('id');
                $(this).removeAttr('style');
            });
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z7jhkxo8/

Comment: please see this and change: jsfiddle.net/masoudnkh/qzwm547u

Comment: @masoudnkh your code was very difficult to read. I refactored it and fixed some issues. Please take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: thaaannnks Lajos, this code worked good. sorry, can you solve this problem on another code? i see recent code solved but im not a developer. last code is in: https://jsfiddle.net/masoudnkh/w5nmjbq7/

Comment: @masoudnkh your PHP code will not run properly in the Fiddle. I will help you if, instead of your PHP code you take a look in your browser (right-click anywhere, click on page source and you will see the generated HTML running in your browser). PHP is templating your view, but I do not have your php code and therefore I cannot fix it. If you intend this to be solved with your PHP code, then you will need to provide more information about the values that PHP outputs. But that's unnecessary from this question's point of view, it's better to take a look at page source.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Thanks.

Comment: Can i have your email? I will send full php file to you. This is one file of wordpress theme and have bug and seller not support me from 2 month ago

Comment: Dear Lajos, you can download full php from https://mega.nz/file/VdtFiQCK#Yqhf7dkOhZ3di3au6ZebUUMzccaZlN8di87VO5_hhtA

Comment: @masoudnkh you didn't close the main div in the structure you are about to add and you have some parsing issues as well. I have fixed your code, you can see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/30wvqo1a/1/

Comment: @masoudnkh your PHP values cannot be determined solely from the file you have sent, because that file is part of a larger environment and assumes its existence. To simplify matters, I assumed values for your PHP variables, your main issue is with parsing. Please look how I organized your code. Apply this to your site and then gradually introduce your PHP code there as well.

Comment: WoooW good. thanks friend. I bought this theme and the developer not support me. But you are awesome man. thanks thanks thanks